# Stata coefplot: plot coefficients and corresponding confidence intervals on 2nd axis

Tags: stata, axis, confidence-interval, coefplot

When trying to depict two coefficients from one regression on separate axes with Ben Jann's superb `coefplot` (`ssc install coefplot`) command, the coefficient to be shown on the 2nd axis is correctly displayed, but its confidence interval is depicted on the 1st scale.

Can anyone explain how I get the CI displayed on the same (2nd) axis as the coefficient it belongs to? I couldn't find any option to change this - and imagine it should be the default, if not the only, option to plot the CI around the point estimate it belongs to.

I use the latest coefplot version with Stata 16.

Here is a minimum example to illustrate the problem:

[results plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEUl4.png)

```
webuse union, clear
eststo results: reg idcode i.union grade
coefplot (results, keep(1.union)) (results, keep(grade) xaxis(2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
coefplot (results, keep(1.union)) (results, keep(grade) xaxis(2))
```

you specify the option `xaxis(2)`, but this is not a documented option of `coefplot`, although it is a valid option of `twoway rspike` which is called by `coefplot`. Apparently, if you use `xaxis(2)` something goes wrong with the communication between `coefplot` and `rspike`.

This works for me:

```
coefplot (results, keep(1.union)) (results, keep(grade) axis(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to create something similar. Since this option is not built-in we need to write a program to tweak how coefplot works. I'm sharing the code from the user manual here: http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/coefplot/markers.html

```
capt program drop coefplot_mlbl
*! version 1.0.0  10jun2021  Ben Jann
program coefplot_mlbl, sclass
    _parse comma plots 0 : 0
    syntax [, MLabel(passthru) * ]
    if `"`mlabel'"'=="" local mlabel mlabel(string(@b, "%5.2f") + " (" + string(@ll, "%5.2f") + "; " + string(@ul, "%5.2f") + ")")
    preserve
    qui coefplot `plots', `options' `mlabel' generate replace nodraw
    sreturn clear
    tempvar touse
    qui gen byte `touse' = __at<.
    mata: st_global("s(mlbl)", ///
        invtokens((strofreal(st_data(.,"__at","`touse'")) :+ " " :+ ///
        "`" :+ `"""' :+ st_sdata(.,"__mlbl","`touse'") :+ `"""' :+ "'")'))
    sreturn local plots `"`plots'"'
    sreturn local options `"`options'"'
end

capt program drop coefplot_ymlbl
*! version 1.0.0  10jun2021  Ben Jann
program coefplot_ymlbl
    _parse comma plots 0 : 0
    syntax [, MLabel(str asis) * ]
    _parse comma mlspec mlopts : mlabel
    local mlopts = substr(`"`mlopts'"', 2, .) // remove leading comma
    if `"`mlspec'"'!="" local mlabel mlabel(`mlspec')
    else                local mlabel
    coefplot_mlbl `plots', `options' `mlabel'
    coefplot `plots',  ///
        yaxis(1 2) yscale(alt) yscale(axis(2) alt noline) ///
        ylabel(none, axis(2)) yti("", axis(2)) ///
        ymlabel(`s(mlbl)', axis(2) notick angle(0) `mlopts') `options'
end

coefplot_ymlbl D F, drop(_cons) xline(0)
```

However, the above program does not allow for the option 'bylabel'. I get a stata error saying "bylabel not allowed". I wanted to ask if there is a way to edit this code and include the bylabel option which is used to label subplots?